# How to assign drop-down `{{selected}}` values to `<tags-input ng-model="tags">`

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Instead of typing inside a  tag-input  user can select values from drop-down and those `{{selected}}` value should assign to `{{tags}}` so it will create the respective tag.

Here is the working  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4476ns7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it.

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags()" load-on-focus="true"
                 load-on-empty="true"></auto-complete>
```

will provide same functionality as selection tag.

Answer (score 0):

add `ng-change="someFunc()"` on your select input.

```
$scope.someFunc = function() {
  $scope.tags.push('tag object to add');
}
```